# Converge in mean square of sum of random variables

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Let $X_n$ and $Y_n$ be two dependent sequences of random variables that converge in the mean square sense to X and Y, respectively.

The question is whether sequence $X_n + Y_n$ converge in the mean square sense, and if so, to what limit?

Here is what I have tried:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}E[(X_n+Y_n-X-Y)^2]=\lim_{n\to\infty}E[(X_n-X)^2]+\lim_{n\to\infty}E[(Y_n-Y)^2]+\lim_{n\to\infty}2Cov((X_n-X)(Y_n-Y))=0+0+\lim_{n\to\infty}2Cov((X_n-X)(Y_n-Y))$

But this is where I get stuck, because I don't know how to proceed forward. What is the $\lim_{n\to\infty}2Cov((X_n-X)(Y_n-Y))$? Is it bounded so that $X_n + Y_n$ converge in some mean square?

Comment: Two comments: (i) It seems you are trying to show convergence to $\mu_X + \mu_Y$.  But actually you should be trying to show convergence to $X+Y$. (ii) Do you know the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality ?

Comment: For example, you are given that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E[(X_n-X)^2]=0$, you are not given that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E[(X_n-\mu_X)^2]=0$. But your calculation seems to assume the latter.

Comment: I see. I corrected the factor 2 error. I think I should also take a look at Cauchy-Schwatz inequality. I will get back tomorrow.

Comment: @Michael $\mu_X$ -> $X$ and $\mu_y$-> $Y$ corrected. Thanks a lot Michael!